# NumPy Vectorize a function, unknown shape

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have function that take numpy array as parameter, for example:

```
def f(arr):
  return arr.sum()
```

and I want to create numpy array from each vec in A, so if `A.shape = (14,12,7)`, my function `myfunc(A).shape = (14,12)`
i.e.
`myfunc(A)[x, y] = f(A[x, y])`

Note that `len(A.shape)` is not specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply [sum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) along the last axis:

```
A.sum(axis=-1)
```

For example:

```
In [1]: np.ones((14,12,7)).sum(axis=-1).shape
Out[1]: (14, 12)
```

If you have a generic function you can use [apply_along_axis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
np.apply_along_axis(sum, -1, A)
```

Comment: I know. the sum function is not the point. It's only example.

Comment: You can put `f` in  apply_along_axis

Comment: If the shape is unknown, as the title suggests, you would want to use `axis=-1` better.

Comment: Good catch ... Thank